# How do I reset Apache's RewriteCond directive?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewritecond

I have some Apache configuration like this:

```
# Image hotlinking rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://badsite\.com/
RewriteRule .*/static/artwork/.*\.(jpg|png)$ /static/images/hotlink.png [L]

# Redirects
RewriteRule ^static/artwork/(.+)$    http://cdn.mysite.com/artwork/$1    [L,R=301]

# CodeIgniter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

It should do the following:

1. If a request for an image comes from `badsite.com`, block it and display the hotlink image instead.
2. If a regular request for an image comes in, redirect to the image hosted on the cdn subdomain.
3. Otherwise, if the request is not a file or directory, load a web page page (goes through CodeIgniter).

However, I think the first `RewriteCond` is applying to the redirect rule, not the hotlinking rule, because requests for images from that referrer are redirected to the CDN, not the hotlinking image. An [example in the Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) (bottom of the section) implies that a line break stops `RewriteCond` applying, but that's not happening.

Is there a way to "reset" the `RewriteCond` rule, or is there some other error in my config?

Comment: are you trying to redirect only from `badsite.com`? or from many sites?

Comment: No, I want to show hotlink.png when the referer is badsite.com, and redirect otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Line breaks are completely inconsequential; a `RewriteCond` only ever applies to one `RewriteRule`; the one directly below it.

Providing more information about your configuration would be helpful, as context is relevant in Apache.  But, from the fact that your second `RewriteRule` works, it seems that this configuration is either set in a `<Directory>` context or an `.htaccess` file, and that `/static` is at the root of that context.

Given that, you first `RewriteRule` will never match.  Change your pattern..

```
.*/static/artwork/.*\.(jpg|png)$
```

..to..

```
^static/artwork/.*\.(jpg|png)$
```

Comment: You're right, the rules were in a Directory context, your correction fixed it, thanks!